# Where does Google Play Services come from on the Oculus Go

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, oculusgo

I missed the [memo](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/mobilesdk/latest/concepts/book-intro/) on the Oculus Go not supporting Firebase (because it doesn't come with Google Play Services installed) and got the Firebase Auth system working for my VR game with the SDK version `5.3.0`. When I upgraded to SDK version `5.3.1` I got a system dialog "{my app} won't run without play services which weren't supported by your device". I found out Firebase updated the required Google Play Services  version when they updated the SDK to `5.3.1`, so my question is: where did the outdated GPS come from and can it can relied on (hah!) to stay there?

Answer (score 1):

Based from [Eveything you need to know to develop for Oculus Go](https://developer.oculus.com/blog/everything-you-need-to-know-to-develop-for-oculus-go/) documentation:

**Gear VR compatability**

> **Google Play Services:** Unlike the Samsung Galaxy devices that run Gear
>   VR, Oculus Go does not ship with Google Play Services installed. You
>   cannot rely on Google Play Services (e.g. Google Firebase, Google
>   Cloud Messaging, etc.), or third-party libraries that depend on Google
>   Play Services (e.g. OneSignal) when running on Oculus Go.

Therefore some applications have automatically opted-out of distribution in Oculus Go because they contain compatability problems. You can opt an application back into Oculus Go distribution by fixing the compatibility errors (e.g. dependency on GPS) and uploading a new build.

Comment: I'm wondering why my application works on the Oculus go when it requires Google play services and supposedly the Oculus go doesn't come with them installed